# Google Analytics - get unique page views

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to get unique page (ga:users ?) views through Google API, but there is some inconstistency with returned number and number, that I see in Google Analytics web interface.

Actually, the number returned by API is every time smaller by few visits. For example, in GA web interface I see 39 unique visit for certain URL, but API returns me 37.

Which one is right and why is there difference?

For normal (non-unique) page views I don't see this problem - numbers are same.

I am using PHP and this is the responsible piece of code

```
$a = $Google_AnalyticsService->data_ga->get(
   MY_TABLE_ID,
   '2014-06-02',
   '2014-06-02',
   'ga:pageViews, ga:users',
   array('filters' => 'ga:pagePath==/my-url')
);
```

however, when I debug it using http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/ , results are still not consistent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are mixing various metrics. To make it clear:

- **ga:users** = Users in web interface, represent number of unique users.
- **ga:pageviews** = Pageviews in web interfrace, number of pageviews.
- **ga: uniquePageviews** = Unique Pageviews in web interface. The number of different (unique) pages within a session.

If you use **Unique Pageviews** metric in regard to specific pages, then it actually means **Visits** (recently renamed to Sessions in GA web interface). It tells you how many visits included (1 or more) pageview of that page. A bit more detailed explanation can be found in [GA Help Documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1257084?hl=en-GB#pageviews_vs_unique_views).

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Glad I could be of service :-)